# returning rendered markdown with express and marked

Tags: node.js, express, markdown, javascript-marked

So I am running a small test application to return the contents of a markdown file in html when a route is visited. I am using marked to render the markdown (https://github.com/chjj/marked).

Here us what I have so far -

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var path = __dirname + '/markdown/test.md'
  var file = fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    return data.toString()
  })
  res.send(marked(file))
})
```

When I navigate to localhost:3000 I'm getting  -

TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
Please report this to https://github.com/chij/marked.

I'm fairly certain I'm trying to send a string, and it res.send('Hello World!') works just fine. Sorry I'm new to both Node and express so I'm still figuring things out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to assign the data of the file to a variable, you should try the [`fs.readFileSync()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) method.

**Synchronous Solution**

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var path = __dirname + '/markdown/test.md';
  var file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
  res.send(marked(file.toString()));
});
```

**Asynchronous Solution**

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var path = __dirname + '/markdown/test.md';
  fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.send(marked(data.toString()));
  });
});
```

**Promisified Solution**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'); // Require 'bluebird' in your package.json file, and run npm install.
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  fs.readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, '/markdown/test.md')).then(function(val) {
    res.send(marked(val.toString()));
  });
});
```

Because asynchronous programming will move on to the next step, running the previous one in a separate thread, accessing data assigned asynchronously outside of the callback function may result in a race condition. If you want to use it asynchronously, you can either handle the response within the asynchronous callback function, or convert it to a promise.

Information on Promises:

[Asynchronous Programming in JavaScript with Promises](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx)

[Promise.js](https://www.promisejs.org/)

[Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird#quick-start) (Another promise lib)

Comment: @Xander Happy to help :) I aslo just added an example with promises.